# Everything Search Engine

Tags: programming-languages

I'm not sure whether I'm in the right place to ask this and if I'm not, please point me to the right Stack Exchange site.

An NTFS file system search engine called 'Everything' can be downloaded from http://www.voidtools.com/
and because it performs so well, I got curious as to what programming language was it written in.

I've searched the above site's forums and google with no success..
I understand that the application is proprietary freeware and so I will not be able to obtain the source code. However, I've never heard of any apps where info about what language it is written in is hidden.

So my question is:  **What language was 'Everything' written in?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

by David » Tue Jul 28, 2009 1:37 am

> 98% C
> 1% C++
> 1% assembly

The above quote is from a forum post by a Site Admin named David which I am assuming is very likely to be David Carpenter who is the author of Everything.

Quoted from:
https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=375#p802 ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20221112195830/https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=375))